# How to enable esc key on vuetify tab

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify. Actually, I have a dialog with tabs.

[image]

I like to close the dialog by esc. Therefore i added the event into the dialog:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-dialog
            v-model="dialog"
            persistent
            max-width="1600px"
            :overlay-color="backgroundColors.calculation"
            @keydown.esc="closeDialog(true)"
        >
```

When I open the dialog, the function works as expected. But when I change the tab, the escape key doesn't work anymore.

I tried to add the `@keydown.esc`to the tab-component:

```
                    <CustomerProjectTabs @keydown.esc="closeDialog"></CustomerProjectTabs>
```

Then I added it to the tab header and tab item:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-tabs
            v-model="tab"
            @keydown.esc="closeDialog"
        >
```

```
            <v-tab-item
                value="customerProject"
                @keydown.esc="closeDialog"
            >
                <ShowCustomerProject></ShowCustomerProject>
            </v-tab-item>
```

The @keydown functions doesn't work.

Where I have to add the @keydown function to make it work after tab changes?

Comment: I found one thing that if you click somewhere in the dialog  after changing the tab it will working fine . i think there may be some reactivity problem.

Comment: In your case you are using persistent with @keydown so that might be the reason